# Tkinter determine keyboard layout

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to detect current keyboard layout in Tkinter?

It is necessary to process keyboard accelerators correctly for such languages as Russian, French, Greek (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455625/tkinter-international-bind) for details).

Comment: The report linked in your question does suggest an approach to it, did you check it at http://bugs.python.org/issue1794#msg86386 ? If that doesn't help you, explain why. Also, do you know how to correctly detect the current keyboard layout using anything else ? I remember Ubuntu having a hard time to detect even my mostly typical keyboards sometimes.

Comment: I quoted my workaround which is similar to the recipe given in your link as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474957/237105) to my original question along with my ideas over why it could be bad.

Comment: As for determining keyboard layout in general - at least in Windows it is pretty feasible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291509/how-to-get-the-code-page-of-the-current-keyboard-layout?rq=1

Comment: That is very different from determining the keyboard layout, that is simply returning the active layout. What if the active layout is wrong ? Your workaround is not similar, it is completely different.

Comment: In the mentioned workaround (msg86386) gpolo sets up a function and catches a keycode that corresponds to the necessary physical button. I do the same thing, although I translated the keycode back to verbose 'keysym' (for example see a translation table [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) and catch it in the ordinary way. Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: There is in fact no general solution built in Tk currently. First I though the workaround could simply be extended to consider `event.char` too, but I don't think that will work either.

Comment: I looked through all the fields of the `event` and none corresponded to the scancode (position of the key on the keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `keysym` is "??" if layout is not english.

```
def key_callback(e):
    # Generate Ctrl-V if current layout is not english
    if e.state & 4 > 0 and chr(e.keycode) == 'V' and e.keysym == "??":
        root.focus_get().event_generate("<<Paste>>")
root.bind("<Key>", key_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature built into Tkinter.

Why not simply have your application ask the user where each special key is, the first time the app starts up? Apple does this with OSX -- it asked me to press a couple of keys the very first time I booted up a fresh install.

You can put the focus into a widget and bind to `<Any-KeyPress>`, and from that grab enough information to bind to whatever key they pressed.

Comment: An example application for wxPython performs "translation" of keyboard accelerators flawlessly without any intervention on my side (under Windows). And yet you say that it is impossible to accomplish in Tkinter.

Comment: To ask user every single keyboard accelerator is unnecessary burden. I've only seen it in `mc` under linux and that's one of the worst things about midnight commander )

Comment: > You can put the focus  
Yep, that's what I currently do for that, and the result is in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474957/237105) to the original question